# How to convert multiple lines of strings into a text file

Tags: python, string, for-loop, text, text-files

I wrote a code that will calculate the mover distance between two text files. The code and the output is below:

```
with open('law.txt',"r",encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:

  for line in f:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    sims = instance[stripped_line]
    print ('Query:')
    print (stripped_line)

    for i in range(num_best):
        print
        print ('similarity = %.4f' % sims[i][1])
        print (corpus_ak[sims[i][0]])
```

```
[2] Out:

Query:
purpose
similarity = 0.8638
Purpose
similarity = 0.6915
Surplus lines brokers and insurance producers; prohibited acts
Query:
definitions
similarity = 0.9064
Definitions
similarity = 0.7963
Licensing of persons in a financial institution
Query:
unfair trade practices prohibited
similarity = 0.8501
Unfair marketing practices prohibited
similarity = 0.8201
Unfair methods, deceptive acts prohibited
Query:
unfair trade practices defined
similarity = 0.8320
Procedures as to undefined practices
similarity = 0.7845
Unfair discrimination and rebates prohibited in property and casualty insurance
Query:
misrepresentations and false advertising of insurance policies
similarity = 0.9570
Misrepresentation and false advertising of insurance policies
similarity = 0.8290
False or misleading financial statements
Query:
false information and advertising generally
similarity = 0.8286
False information, advertising
similarity = 0.8023
Misrepresentation and false advertising of insurance policies
Query:
defamation
similarity = 0.8756
Defamation
similarity = 0.7741
Proof and method of mailing notice
Query:
boycott, coercion and intimidation
similarity = 0.9615
Boycott, coercion, and intimidation
similarity = 0.8229
Anticoercion and antitying
:
:
:
:
Query:
separability provision
similarity = 0.7733
Violation of viatical settlement provisions prohibited
similarity = 0.7493
Provisions of this chapter additional to other law
```

What I want to do is to convert the output into a text file, which can store the results. I want the output text file to look something like below:

```
Query:
purpose
similarity = 0.8638
Purpose
similarity = 0.6915
Surplus lines brokers and insurance producers; prohibited acts

Query:
definitions
similarity = 0.9064
Definitions
similarity = 0.7963
Licensing of persons in a financial institution

Query:
unfair trade practices prohibited
similarity = 0.8501
Unfair marketing practices prohibited
similarity = 0.8201
Unfair methods, deceptive acts prohibited

Query:
unfair trade practices defined
similarity = 0.8320
Procedures as to undefined practices
similarity = 0.7845
Unfair discrimination and rebates prohibited in property and casualty insurance
:
:
:
:
:
Query:
separability provision
similarity = 0.7733
Violation of viatical settlement provisions prohibited
similarity = 0.7493
Provisions of this chapter additional to other law
```

I am wondering are there anyways for me to achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use write to store those strings in txt file for example:

```
some_string='hello word'
some_string2='hello space'
with open('strings.txt' mode='w') as s:
s.write(f'{some_strings}\n{some_strings2}')
```

Comment: Thank you, Dexter. But I am wondering how can implement it into my for loop without overwriting the previous line?

Comment: can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: So my for loop will keep generating the moving distance score until the end of the `law.txt` file. I am just wondering how can I implement codes that can store/write the output of my for loop into a new text file

Comment: you can use 
```
for statement:
with open('result.txt' , mode='w')as r:
r.write(f'{your variable in which result is stored }\n')